# Bezier circles getting cropped on the mac

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin

My app runs on Mac and iOS. (two code bases with lots of shared code).

I have a piece of common code that converts a shape to a NSBezierPath/UIBezierPath.
The code is identical between the two - except for the NS*/UI*.
I then create a CAShapeLayer and set the path for the layer to the Bezier path.
That layer is added to a set of layers in the view. Again... common code between iOS and Mac.

One type of shape is a simple circle.
To create this I call:

```
path.AddArc(point.CGPoint(), width/2, 0, (float)(2 * Math.PI), true);
```

When I add this to my layer... I get a clipped circle, but only on the Mac. On iOS this works perfectly.

[image: Clipped on Mac with AddArc]

I tried switching to AppendPathWithOvalInRect:

```
path.AppendPathWithOvalInRect(rect);
```

That provides a slightly different clip direction:

[image: Clipped on Mac with Oval]

The layer construction is very simple, and identical between Mac and iOS.

```
var layer = new CAShapeLayer();
layer.LineWidth = 0f;
layer.FillColor = color;
layer.StrokeColor = color;
layer.Path = GetBezier().CGPath();

objectLayer.AddSubLayer(layer);
```

I can see no evidence of masks or clipping on any other object. Just all my circles, and only on the Mac.

I've also included below an example of a number of simple objects - lines, fat lines, circles. You can see that all circles have this weird clipping.

[image: Clipping only on circles]

Any thoughts on what I might be missing here?
Thx for your help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a solution.

It turns out I was missing a ClosePath().

Interestingly... iOS does not need the ClosePath call.
On the Mac, the following calls *do* need a ClosePath call:
AddArc, FromOvalInRect, AppendPathWithArc.
The following call did not seem to need a ClosePath call:
FromRoundedRect
because I could use that to draw a perfect circle.